# make an android app in which the launch icon is working as a link

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if it is possible to make an android app and when the user hits the launch icon, the browser opens with a specific URL. I know that you can make shortcuts on your phone home screen with the URL you want but I was wondering if it is possible as an android app. So the app should don almost nothing just when i tap on it the browser should open..

is this possible? and is yes how should I think it?

Comment: yes possible. Open the browser.

Comment: haha...i would want for some users who are lazy to write an url or to bookmark an url just to tap an icon..please don't make useless coments..

Comment: Then please don't ask off-topic questions :D  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What makes you think that users who are too lazy to create a bookmark are not too lazy to download an app?

Comment: this is just a demand..who am i to judge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this in the main activity's onCreate:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
```

in the manifest add noDisplay theme:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```